# How to make servo reach the desired angle slowly?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, servo

I found a solution that make a servo reach a desired angle step by step , But it depends on the current angle of servo .
this is the code :

```
    if servo_current angle > servo_desired_angle :
        while(x=true) :
             servo_current_angle -=1 
             duty_cycle = (((12.5-2.5)/(180-0) * servo_current_angle) +2.5 
             p.ChangeDutyCycle (duty_cycle)
             time.sleep(0.01)
             if servo_current angle = servo_desired_angle :
                 x = false 
    elif servo_current_angle < servo_desired_angle :
         while(x=true) :
             servo_current_angle +=1 
             duty_cycle = (((12.5-2.5)/(180-0) * servo_current_angle) +2.5 
             p.ChangeDutyCycle (duty_cycle)
             time.sleep(0.01)
             if servo_current angle = servo_desired_angle :
                 x = false
```

the problem is How to know servo_current_angle ?

Comment: could you give some more information about your hardware and your overall goal?

Comment: My overall goal to make servo not to go the desired angle directly . I want it to reach that angle step by step to achieve smoothing in move .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a typical open-loop hobby servo (one with no feedback encoder) there is no way to know the position at all.  All you can do is supply a pulse as described above and trust that the servo's load will not prevent it from moving to the commanded position.   Other options:

- You can add an encoder of your own like a digital or optical encoder.
- You can change to closed-loop servos (much more expensive) that have encoders built in like the Dynamixel line.

To address your problem of smoother step by step movement, you need to command it to intermediate positions between the current position and the desired position.  Think of it as taking 20 (in the example below) tiny steps instead of one big step.  To do that, use a loop to update the duty cycle. Here is an example:

```
current duty_cycle = 7.5 
desired_duty_cycle = 5.0
steps = 20.0
duty_cycle_delta = (desired_duty_cycle - current_duty_cycle) / steps
while (current_duty_cycle != desired_duty_cycle):
    if (current_duty_cycle > desired_duty_cycle):
        duty_cycle_delta = -duty_cycle_delta
    current_duty_cycle = current_duty_cycle + duty_cycle_delta
    p.ChangeDutyCycle (current_duty_cycle)
```

This will approach the desired position by commanding intermediate positions until the desired position is reached.  Alter the `steps` variable to alter the speed that it approaches the desired position.

Comment: on my el-cheapo ES08A that jitters mercilessly

Comment: @Phlip Perhaps.  This method works best on medium- to upper-grade digital servos at ~60 Hz or higher.  I actually used this approach on a hexapod robot, with pre-calculated bezier acceleration and deceleration curves between end positions, and it was smooth as silk with decent digital servos at 90 Hz.

Comment: since the requirement is "roll forward at a set speed," I'm seeing if our hardware guy can go with less servo and more stepper...

Answer (score 0):

> What about tracking the current servo position during runtime and
>   update it along the way?
>
> You can use the [PWM module in
>   RPi.GPIO](http://rpi.science.uoit.ca/lab/servo/) and in the beginning move
>   the servo into its initial position to start from.

The position of the servo motor is set by the length of a pulse. The servo expects to receive a pulse at least every 20 milliseconds. If that pulse is high for 1 millisecond, the servo angle will be zero; if it is 1.5 milliseconds, it will be at its center position; and if it is 2 milliseconds, it will be at 180 degrees.

[image: Servomotors]

The example program sets the PWM frequency to 100 Hz, which will send a pulse to the servo every 10 milliseconds. The angle is converted into a duty cycle between 0 and 100. This actually produces pulses shorter than the 1 millisecond expected minimum value and longer than 2 milliseconds maximum.

Source [here](http://razzpisampler.oreilly.com/ch05.html)

Comment: this is from your source : **def update(self, angle):
        duty = float(angle) / 10.0 + 2.5
        pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(duty) ** i don't want to go to angle directly .. thanks in anyway :) .

Comment: I know you said that, still what is your exact problem then? To find out the initial position?

Comment: I meant current position during process , not intial position . Should i store the previous desired position as currunt position in eeprom ?